# JAXB unmarshall with multi namespace

Tags: jaxb, marklogic, jaxb2, marklogic-8

I have a xml from third part.

```
<cts:element-value-query weight="0">
   <cts:element xmlns:_1="entitlement:AAA">_1:Entitlement</cts:element>
   <cts:text xml:lang="en">TEST</cts:text>
</cts:element-value-query>
```

Or :

```
<cts:element-value-query weight="0">
   <cts:element xmlns:_1="entitlement:BBB">_1:Entitlement</cts:element>
   <cts:text xml:lang="en">CASE</cts:text>
</cts:element-value-query>
```

I want to unmarshall the xml to Java bean:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "element-value-query", namespace= "http://marklogic.com/cts")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Query4ElementValue {

@XmlElement(name= "element", namespace="entitlement:AAA")
private String element;

private String text;
}
```

I can get the correct text value, but for the `element`, always null.

`[element=null, text=TEST]`

How can I do then ?

Comment: Is the goal binding on the query representation or on the documents matched by the query?

The namespace of cts:element is "http://marklogic.com/cts"  The _1 namespace binding applies to the _1:Entitlement text content of the cts:element.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<cts:element xmlns:_1="entitlement:AAA">_1:Entitlement</cts:element>
```

Is an element with the name `element` in the `cts` namespace.

Your mapping:

```
@XmlElement(name= "element", namespace="entitlement:AAA")
private String element;
```

Expects an element with the name `element` in the namespace with the URI `entitlement:AAA`. Which is probably not the `cts` namespace you're providing.

If you're interested in getting `_1:Entitlement` with `_1` bound to `entitlement:AAA` or `entitlement:BBB`, change the type of the element to `QName`.